# trying to use foreach after html escaping

Tags: php

This is going to make me look silly, but I'm trying do an foreach after some HTML without breaking out the `$html = 'my html code';` here's what I'm attempting to do, although getting an `foreach` error thrown at me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH`

Here's the code :

```
$html = "
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    playlist: [".foreach($myVideos as $video) {
        echo "{";
        echo "file: 'http://www.website.com/".$video[filename]."'";
        echo "}";
    }."]
});";
```

It's obviously very basic yet I just can't seem to get rid of this, I'm overlooking something I just can't see what

Comment: Your post is a good example of an XY problem. You're approaching this the wrong way. If you want your `playlist:` to be a proper JavaScript object, have a look at `json_encode` – you can do this without manually building a string.

Comment: @curtis, please take some time to review my answer. It may not solve your problem right away, but should lead you to a newer approach.

Comment: Even if you make this work in PHP, it would still cause a parse error in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use foreach within a string assignment, Try this instead. Note: to get comma's between the individual objects in your playlist and ensure that the values are escape properly I am creating an array of videos and using json_encode to product the final output.

```
$html = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {playlist: ";
$vids = array();
foreach($myVideos as $video) {
        $vids[] = array("file"=>"http://www.website.com/".$video["filename"]);
    }
$html.= json_encode($vids);
$html."});";
```

But I suspect this is going to product invalid JSON data because of the lack of , between the elements.

A better approach might be to do this (php 5.3 and above)

```
$videoList = array_map(function($a){ return array("file"=>"http://www.website.com/".$a["filename"]."'"); }, $myVideos);
$html = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {playlist:".json_encode($videoList)."});";
```

Comment: @Curtis I think the missing commas in the json array are going to make the original string invalid. I provided an alternative with better json encoding support and I will update the original implementions to add the commas where needed

Comment: Okay, now it's just the JavaScript that doesn't make sense, not sure what OP expects from that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to start a loop in the middle of creating a string.  You can't do that.

Instead add to the string inside your loop. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
$html = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    playlist: [";

foreach($myVideos as $video) {
        $html .= "{";
        $html .=  "file: 'http://www.website.com/".$video[filename]."'";
        $html .=  "}";
}

$html .= "]});";
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything here is wrong. You can not concatenate $html with foreach.
If you want content of what's inside foreach you should concatenate, not echo. At least try this:

```
$html = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    playlist: [";
foreach($myVideos as $video) {
        $html .= "{file: 'http://www.website.com/" . $video[filename]."'}";
    }

$html .= "]
});";
```

Next thing - consider passing arrays to js using [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php), it is designed to be used in js, it does necessary escaping and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the XY problem (basically this is a problem caused by a poor understanding of your instruments, more info [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

You're looking to return a json-encoded string. Why not try the following?

```
$jsonArr = array()
foreach($myVideos as $video) {
    $jsonArr[] = "http://www.website.com/".$video[filename];
}
$json = json_encode($jsonArr);
$html = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) { playlist: [$json]});";
```

Please note this is untested and you might have to juggle a bit with square and curly braces, but it should direct you on a new, better and cleaner path.

Answer (score 0):

You still did not complete your string. it expects a ; before foreach. Even if that could work echo parts would output to browser and not in to your string you could do:

```
$html = "
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {playlist: [";
foreach($myVideos as $video) {
    $html .= "{file: 'http://www.website.com/".$video[filename]."'}";
}
$html.= "]});";
```

`.=` appends yo your string.

---

Also it appears you are trying to create a json string whty not directly json_encode your $myVideos array?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do it by pulling the foreach out to its own statement, like so:

```
$html = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) { playlist: [";

foreach($myVideos as $video) 
{
    $html = $html."{ file: 'http://www.website.com/".$video[filename]."' }";
}

$html = $html."]});";
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to echo $html after all this...

```
    $html = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        playlist: [";

    foreach($myVideos as $video) {
            $html .= "{";
            $html .=  "file: 'http://www.website.com/".$video[filename]."'";
            $html .=  "}";
    }

    $html .= "]});";
    echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on building the right data structure first and then generate the surrounding code:

```
$playList = array();
foreach($myVideos as $video) {
    $playList[] = array(
        'file' => 'http://www.website.com/' . urlencode($video[filename]),
    );
}

$script = 'jQuery(function($) {
    var playList = ' . json_encode($playList) . ';
    // etc
});';
```